# Intercept system wide Mac OS X SpeechSynthesizer events when using text to speech

Tags: objective-c, macos, text-to-speech

I would like to write an app for the Mac that intercepts the built in way the OS handles text to speech.  It would need to be triggered by receiving the event "Somebody has started the standard 'start speaking' functionality".

From reading the [Speech synthesis programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/SpeechSynthesisProgrammingGuide/SpeechOverview/SpeechOverview.html) it would seem that the speech synthesis framework is somehow pluggable and would be a suitable place to intercept the incoming TTS requests. Unfortunately the documents especially doesn't offer insight to how interception could be done globally. Where can I learn how I would go about implementing such an interception scheme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience with the API I am pretty sure that the only way to access this information globally is polling NSSpeechSynthesizer’s `+isAnyApplicationSpeaking` or `SpeechBusySystemWide()`. You can try binding to the former, but I think that I have tried and that it it isn’t KVO-complient.

Comment: I see, but even if those methods would send me the event, I wouldn't be able to truly intercept the tts request call. Another method might be to create a kind of 'pseudo-voice' that delegates the TTS functionality to the other available voices. Do you know about any information on how to create your own 'custom voice' programmatically? It should be a public api, considering there seem to be 3rd party providers for those voices - but I cannot find any information on those either.

Comment: Interesting approach @keyboardsamurai! There is the Morse “voice” sample code. You will currently run into some trouble getting it to actually build AFAIK. Check https://lists.apple.com/mailman/options/speech-dev/.

Comment: Awesome - it looks like that is exactly what I needed. Thanks a  lot. I found the Morse code example on https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/MorseSynthesizer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011314-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

Comment: @keyboardsamurai did you get this to work for you.  I am using the text to speech a lot.  I would like to modify the way it reads some kinds of content.. Like Slack Discussions..